# Android - Bad notification posted only on Android 2.3

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm receiving reports about crash in Android 2.3 when displaying notification.
The stacktrace I have is:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.megadevs.hubi: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.megadevs.hubi id=1 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x62))
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1048)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've read that Android 2.3 have some issue with AnimatedImageView, but I don't think I'm using it...
The code I run for displaying the notification is:

```java
NotificationCompat2.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat2.Builder(getApplicationContext());
notification = builder.setOngoing(true)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat2.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    .setSmallIcon(notificationSmallIcon)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
    .setContentTitle(downloads.elements().nextElement().getFileName())
    .setProgress(100, (int) downloadable.getDownload().getProgress(), false)
    .build();
startForeground(DL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

**UPDATE:**
I've discovered that the problem appears when I try to updated that notification started with startForeground(), the code I run is:

```java
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(android.R.id.progress, 100, (int) download.getProgress(), false);
mNotificationManager.notify(DL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

But it works correctly on ICS and JB, so why is it giving problems on Ginger?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same thing :|

Answer (score 2):

Do not reference notification directly because you are using NotificationBuilder to create your notification object.

Remove:

```
 notification.contentView.setProgressBar(android.R.id.progress, 100, (int) download.getProgress(), false);
```

Add:

```
 builder.setProgress(int max, int progress, boolean indeterminate)
```

Also, it looks like you are using a custom notification layout, see the docs how to use with the builder
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: setProgressBar etc won't really work, since it is Android 4.x+.

Comment: Sorry, i meant setProgress.  fixed above. basically you shouldn't mix the old way of doing notification if you are using the new way, i.e. NotificationBuilder

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing something like android.view.InflateException ? Also please check where you keep notificationSmallIcon? Can you ensure that the png file exists in drawable folder? Not just in drawable-mdpi etc?

Can you post a complete log when you run the application.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I have discovered after some tests. Any ideas?